# How to make the script run automatically to go on?

Tags: bash, apt-get, apt

There is a simple bash script named `test.sh` .

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get install -y build-essential  gcc  libtool  libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev  openssl  libssl-dev
apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

During the runing process `sh test.sh`, a window will pop up to read the changelog, when you press `q`, then it will go on, how to make the script run automatically till the end, not to let the window pop up?

[image]

Comment: The question is about apt-get indeed, not bash. Consider adding [tag:apt] or [tag:apt-get] tags, or [tag:package-managers].

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for the question?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work for you:

```
# export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
# ./test.sh
```

Did you try googling? Here are some links from the first page of "apt-get unattended install" search results:

- http://snowulf.com/2008/12/04/truly-non-interactive-unattended-apt-get-install/
- http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html
- https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Silent-automatic-apt-get-upgrade.html